# `subprocess.call` operates differently to running command directly in shell

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, rsync

I have the following command in Python, which I wrote with the aim of copying only `.yaml` files from a `source` directory (on the network) to a local `target` directory:

```
import subprocess as sp

cmd = ['rsync', '-rvt',  "--include='*/*.yaml'",  "--exclude='*/*'",
     source , destination]

print ' '.join(cmd)
sp.call(cmd)
```

However, when I run this Python, *all* files are copied, including `.jpg` etc.

---

When I run the shell command directly:

```
rsync -rvt --include='*/*.yaml' --exclude='*/*' <source> <target>
```

...then only `.yaml` files are copied, as expected.

---

What is going on here? Why does the command operate differently in shell than under `subprocess.call`?

(This is with a Bash shell on Ubuntu 14.04, using Anaconda's Python 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the single quotes around the wildcards:

```
['rsync', '-rvt',  "--include=*/*.yaml",  "--exclude=*/*",     source , destination]
```

Those quotes are processed by the shell, the shell doesn't pass in the quotes to rsync.